# Difference between executing stored procedure and query (arithmetic overflow because of types)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**The question is: why there is difference how datatypes get converted/interpreted when executing the query and stored procedure?**

I have a stored procedure which gives me:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp****ChargePackagingTest, Line 9
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.
```

The problem is that it happens solely when executed as stored procedure:

```
exec [sp****ChargePackagingTest] '2016-10-14', '2016-10-25'
```

However, if I execute identical query (copied outside the stored procedure and declared with the same parameters and using SQL management studio), I don't experience the problem.

On top of that, I know the precise location of the problem:
    CONVERT(nvarchar(2), JobPDF.Pages / 2)

The stored procedure says problem is in line 9, but actually it's not. If I change it to nvarchar(3), it works even then executing as stored procedure.

However, JobPdf.Pages is nullable int type: values are only 24, 48, 72 (I've checked). Further, it crashes only when there is enough data, i.e., it's not specific to a date range, but to the length of date range.

*Stored procedure code:*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp****ChargePackagingTest]
@dateFrom DateTime, @dateTo DateTime

AS
BEGIN

SELECT costPerOrder****.[Product Name], costPerOrder****.[Pack Price], SUM([Pack Count]) as [Pack Count], SUM(costPerOrder****.[Packaging Cost]) as [Packaging Cost]
FROM
(
    -- Raw data aggregated by order
    SELECT [Product Name], [Pack Price]
    , CEILING(SUM(Quantity) * 1.0 / [Pack Items]) as [Pack Count] -- 1.0 converts it to decimal and uses decimal division
    , CEILING(SUM(Quantity) * 1.0 / [Pack Items])  * [Pack Price] as [Packaging Cost]
    FROM

        (
        -- Raw Polaroid data (basically we creating LookUp_Product and joining with orders)
        select JobDetail.OrderId, ProductName + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2), JobPDF.Pages / 2) as [Product Name]

        , job.Quantity
        , CASE

        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 24 THEN 0.063 -- **** 12 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 48 THEN 0.063 -- **** 24 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 72 THEN 0.089 -- **** 36 pages
        ELSE NULL 
        END as [Pack Price]

        ,CASE

        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 24 THEN 2 -- **** 12 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 48 THEN 2 -- **** 24 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 72 THEN 3 -- **** 36 pages
        ELSE NULL
        END as [Pack Items]

        FROM Job WITH (NOLOCK)
        inner join LookUp_Product WITH (NOLOCK) on LookUp_Product.ProductID = job.ProductID

        inner join JobEvent WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobEvent.JobID = job.JobID
        inner join JobDetail WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobDetail.JobID = job.JobID
        inner join Orders WITH (NOLOCK)  on Orders.OrderId = JobDetail.OrderID
        inner join JobPDF WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobPDF.JobID = job.JobID
        where 1=1

        AND LookUp_Product.ClientID = 'AC7EDBCD-39DF-45CE-8D96-A26EB17D1E2D' 
        AND Job.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A'
        AND JobDetail.CurrentEventID = 999999
        AND JobEvent.EventID = 999999
        AND JobEvent.DateDone >= @dateFrom
        AND JobEvent.DateDone < @dateTo
        AND PackPrice is not null AND PackPrice <> 0.0000
        ) as Raw****Data

    GROUP BY Raw****Data.OrderID, [Product Name], [Pack Price], [Pack Items]) costPerOrder****

GROUP BY [Product Name], [Pack Price]
ORDER BY [Product Name]

END
```

The query execution example:

```
declare @dateFrom DateTime = '2016-10-14'
declare @dateTo DateTime = '2016-10-25'

SELECT costPerOrder****.[Product Name], costPerOrder****.[Pack Price], SUM([Pack Count]) as [Pack Count], SUM(costPerOrder****.[Packaging Cost]) as [Packaging Cost]
FROM
(
    -- Raw data aggregated by order
    SELECT [Product Name], [Pack Price]
    , CEILING(SUM(Quantity) * 1.0 / [Pack Items]) as [Pack Count] -- 1.0 converts it to decimal and uses decimal division
    , CEILING(SUM(Quantity) * 1.0 / [Pack Items])  * [Pack Price] as [Packaging Cost]
    FROM

        (
        -- Raw **** data (basically we creating LookUp_Product and joining with orders)
        select JobDetail.OrderId, ProductName + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2), JobPDF.Pages / 2) as [Product Name]

        , job.Quantity
        , CASE

        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 24 THEN 0.063 -- **** 12 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 48 THEN 0.063 -- **** 24 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 72 THEN 0.089 -- **** 36 pages
        ELSE NULL 
        END as [Pack Price]

        ,CASE

        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 24 THEN 2 -- **** 12 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 48 THEN 2 -- **** 24 pages
        when LookUp_Product.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A' AND JobPDF.Pages = 72 THEN 3 -- ****36 pages
        ELSE NULL
        END as [Pack Items]

        FROM Job WITH (NOLOCK)
        inner join LookUp_Product WITH (NOLOCK) on LookUp_Product.ProductID = job.ProductID

        inner join JobEvent WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobEvent.JobID = job.JobID
        inner join JobDetail WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobDetail.JobID = job.JobID
        inner join Orders WITH (NOLOCK)  on Orders.OrderId = JobDetail.OrderID
        inner join JobPDF WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobPDF.JobID = job.JobID
        where 1=1

        AND LookUp_Product.ClientID = 'AC7EDBCD-39DF-45CE-8D96-A26EB17D1E2D' 
        AND Job.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A'
        AND JobDetail.CurrentEventID = 999999
        AND JobEvent.EventID = 999999
        AND JobEvent.DateDone >= @dateFrom
        AND JobEvent.DateDone < @dateTo
        AND PackPrice is not null AND PackPrice <> 0.0000
        ) as Raw****dData

    GROUP BY Raw****Data.OrderID, [Product Name], [Pack Price], [Pack Items]) costPerOrder****

GROUP BY [Product Name], [Pack Price]
ORDER BY [Product Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more to your data than you have found.  Have you done a `distinct` on the *entire* `JobPDF.Pages` column and not just a 'representative' sample?

As your query works with certain date ranges and not others, I would advise taking the range that doesn't and looking at the `distinct` values being returned as your `arithmetic overflow` can only be because your query is returning more than 2 characters following your division.

The script below illustrates this, in that even though there is data that will cause the `convert` to fail, if it isn't returned by the query in the first place, everything appears to run without issue:

```
declare @a table (a int);
insert into @a values(7155),(72);

-- This query will run
select CONVERT(nvarchar(2), a / 2)
from @a
where a < 100;

-- This query will not
select CONVERT(nvarchar(2), a / 2)
from @a;
```

---

Quite simply I cannot see why there would be any issue other than the above.  Can you please run the following and add the output to your question?  If the dates do not correlate to a range that produces an error, please substitute those dates that do into the below:

```
select distinct JobPDF.Pages

FROM Job WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join LookUp_Product WITH (NOLOCK) on LookUp_Product.ProductID = job.ProductID

inner join JobEvent WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobEvent.JobID = job.JobID
inner join JobDetail WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobDetail.JobID = job.JobID
inner join Orders WITH (NOLOCK)  on Orders.OrderId = JobDetail.OrderID
inner join JobPDF WITH (NOLOCK)  on JobPDF.JobID = job.JobID
where 1=1

AND LookUp_Product.ClientID = 'AC7EDBCD-39DF-45CE-8D96-A26EB17D1E2D' 
AND Job.ProductID = 'AA5DF53B-4B58-4298-AFA3-EE856610689A'
AND JobDetail.CurrentEventID = 999999
AND JobEvent.EventID = 999999
AND JobEvent.DateDone >= '20161014'
AND JobEvent.DateDone < '20161025'
AND PackPrice is not null AND PackPrice <> 0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you.

„Further, it crashes only when there is enough data, i.e., it's not specific to a date range, but to the length of date range.“

It's not about a specific range, not possible to pintpoint to a specific day. 

And I did run the distinct, no anomalies in data.

On top of that, your example doesn't shed ligh on the fact that executing stored procedure doesn't work, while query does. Your sample would crash on both cases.

Comment: @PovilasPanavas  Edited my answer to ask for specific clarification.

Comment: Thank you, again for taking your time and answering my question. I've run your query and the results are: `Pages 24 48 72` 

Also, I've selected select CONVERT(nvarchar(2), JobPDF.Pages / 2) and no problem. I've even put it into a stored procedure, and called it, still no problem.

That means that the problem cannot be isolated to this select, it only happens in conjunction with outer select which picks data from this select.

Btw, the line 9 (error line) is this `SELECT [Product Name], [Pack Price]`. This is the selected columns from the outer select.

Comment: @PovilasPanavas  SSMS simply tells you the start of the query that caused the error, so it is telling you that the error resides in that `select`.  If you move the columns onto the next line, you will still get the error occurring on the `select`.  Try removing your everything in your `where` and then run the `select distinct JobPDF.Pages` to see if there is data other than 24, 48 and 72.